# Threading not working how do i solve this?

Tags: python, sockets

This is not working when I want to access int(COORDINATES[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRGYC.png)) it's not working. How do i fix this? i am trying to access the COODINATES which now  have become a global scope

```
import socket
import os,sys
import time
from threading import Thread

HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

COORDINATES = []

def connect():   
    globals()['client_socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

def update_coordinates():
    connect()
    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0
    while True:
        try:
            client_socket.send("loc\n")
            data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        except:
            connect();
            continue;

        globals()['COORDINATES'] = data.split()

        if(not(COORDINATES[-1] == "eom" and COORDINATES[0] == "start")):
            continue

        if (screen_width != int(COORDINATES[2])):
        screen_width = int(COORDINATES[2])
                screen_height = int(COORDINATES[3])   

Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()

while True:
    print 'ball x' , int(COORDINATES[2])
```

this is the error i got [image]
[image]

and if i change my code to this:

```
    import socket
import os,sys
import time
from threading import Thread

HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

COORDINATES = []

def connect():   
    globals()['client_socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

def update_coordinates():
    connect()
    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0
    while True:
        try:
            client_socket.send("loc\n")
            data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        except:
            connect();
            continue;

        globals()['COORDINATES'] = data.split()

        if(not(COORDINATES[-1] == "eom" and COORDINATES[0] == "start")):
            continue

        if (screen_width != int(COORDINATES[2])):
        screen_width = int(COORDINATES[2])
                screen_height = int(COORDINATES[3]) 

    print int(COORDINATES[8])  

Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
```

and this is what i get:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could post the error you got.

Comment: @user1474837 already edited the question, you can have a look at it now

Comment: I don't see an error - it looks like your script is hanging and not returning. Can you Ctrl-C to stop the script?

Comment: @PeterSobot nope i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Thread(target=update_coordinates()).start()
```

Should read:

```
Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
```

You've provided the result of your function as the value for target, rather than providing the function itself.

Comment: if i change it to Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
 i get this error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Edward - Which is progress, now you're actually getting an exception inside of your function when it runs.  That's progress for you.  That error is probably in the line where you're indexing into COORDINATES.  Check what it's value is before you access it.

Comment: i have edited the question above it prints the value but my goal is to access the values so i could use it in my game control loop? how do i do that?